# Ionic TypeError: b is undefined

Tags: ionic2

I have an Ionic2 app, that has just stopped working (not sure why).

The following command:

```
ionic serve
```

Builds the app with no errors, but when `http://localhost:8100/` is loaded into the browser, I get:

```
TypeError: b is undefined
```

In order to debug this I tried to put a `console.log` at the top of `app.ts` constructor, but this is not being printed.

Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong, or were I should look to try diagnose this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have been doing some more debugging, and I have found that this is related to inheritance of a variable I think.

I have the following code:

**search.ts**

```
export class SearchPage extends SearchSubParentPage {

  constructor(ref: ChangeDetectorRef, nav: NavController, private viewCtrl: ViewController, jobService: JobService, personService: PersonService, utilityService: UtilityService, navParams: NavParams, popoverController: PopoverController, events: Events, platform: Platform, alertCtrl: AlertController, loadingController: LoadingController) {
    super(ref, nav, viewCtrl, jobService, personService, utilityService, navParams, popoverController, events, platform, alertCtrl, loadingController, false, 0);
  }
```

**searchSubParent.ts**

```
export class SearchSubParentPage extends SearchParent {

private popoverController: PopoverController = null;

  constructor(ref: ChangeDetectorRef, nav: NavController, viewCtrl: ViewController, jobService: JobService, personService: PersonService, utilityService: UtilityService, navParams: NavParams, popoverController: PopoverController, events: Events, platform: Platform, alertCtrl: AlertController, loadingController: LoadingController, favourite: boolean, jobType: number) {
    this.popoverController = popoverController;
}
```

As you can see, the `popoverController` object is passed via the constructor to the parent `SearchSubParentPage`.

If I have the following line of code in `SearchSubParentPage`, I get the error:

```
this.popover = this.popoverController.create(SearchJobsPopOverPage, {...
```

If I comment it out, it works. So this suggests that there is something wrong with the way I pass `popoverController` to the parent (I have the same issue with the `nav` object too).

If I `console.log` either `this.popoverController` or `this.nav`, they appear to be fine (i.e. not undefined or null).

Comment: do you have a var named b somewhere? could you show more code?

Comment: or did you by accident hit b on your keyboard in a class?

Comment: I have just updated the above question to have more info. It looks like it's related to how I pass an object from a child to a parent using inheritance. But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If I make the object public, it works, not sure why.

change:

```
private popoverController: PopoverController = null;
```

to:

```
public popoverController: PopoverController = null;
```